# objectId from url to match with one in the mongo using meteorjs

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor js. I got the id from url but i am failing to match it with the id in the mongodb. can any help me

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('post', {
    template:'viewpost',
    path: '/post/:_id',
    data: function () {
     var id = new ObjectID(this.params._id);
      return Tasks.findOne({_id: id});

    }

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want to return a single task? You access the `_id` from `this.params` where `this` refers to the router.

```
Router.map(function () { 
        this.route('post', { 
            template:'viewpost', 
            path: '/post/:_id', 
            data: function () { 
                return Tasks.findOne(this.params._id);
            }
});
```

In your template you can start referring to the task because it will be the data context for the template;

```
<p>{{description}}</p>
```

Assuming you have a description field in your Tasks Collection.

Comment: @Meteorpoly are you talking to me?

Comment: No this comment was for @Mariya James

Comment: Can you provide more information? Any errors in your server or client console?

Comment: No errors are showing on the both side. but when give console inside functions like this  console.log(Tasks.findOne({_id:this.params._id}));    I got undefined  in console

Comment: @MariyaJames I just updated the code to slightly different syntax, let me know if you still receive undefined.