# Meteor - MongoDB _id

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to assign the MongoDB `_id` primary key to a variable but cannot do it. When I look at the record in the collection, the `postID` shows up as `undefined` - code listed below. How can I fix this? I want the `postID` to match the `_id`. Thanks in advance!

```
Template.postNewJob.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var position = $('[name=position]').val();
    var jobDescription = $('[name=jobDescription]').val();
    var createdAt = new Date();
    var createdBy = Meteor.userId();
    var postID = this._id;
    postedJobs.insert({
        position: position,
        jobDescription: jobDescription,
        createdAt: createdAt,
        createdBy: createdBy,
        postID: postID
    });
    Router.go('dashboard');
    }
});
```

Comment: It appears that `this._id` is undefined. Presumably because this is a new post form and not one connected to an existing document? Also you are not assigning `_id` in your `.insert()` statement so you will get a random `_id`. You are trying to assign `postId` instead which is not the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find some helpful info from another posting and was able to solve this issue. The reference page is [objectId from url to match with one in the mongo using meteorjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606616/objectid-from-url-to-match-with-one-in-the-mongo-using-meteorjs)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if postId will always be your document id then there may be another way of doing this. You may use collection hooks . Refer here
https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks

and use a function as below in your server side file

```
postedJobs.after.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  doc.postId=this._id
});
```